# Html file not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is not displaying anything on the browser when opened from a local host. But shows everything when open via live server on VSC Editor

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Expanding Cards</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url(/images/messi.jpg);">
            <h3>Lionel Messi</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/pique.jpg);">
            <h3>Gerard Pique</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/pedri.jpg);">
            <h3>Pedri Gonzalez</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/alba.jpg);">
            <h3>Jordi Alba</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/griezmann.webp);">
            <h3>Antoine Griezmann</h3>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope to find any fix. Please try to review all the sections and i have used the code format correctly

Comment: Look for any errors in the console. Also please provide more detail if you can

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please update your question or it will be downvoted and/or closed. Writing just "I wrote code but it doesn't work" Is not a question in the form required by the community. First please  read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please provide more info on code/any errors?

Comment: You can add information about what is displayed on the application or how did you run this HTML page. @WaliWaqar Looking at the console error is a nice option if the request at least hits the required page.

Comment: You have the reactjs tag in your question. Don't know much about react but could you possibly be opening the site in the browser without running `npm run build`?

Comment: I have pasted the html basic code

Comment: Is your localhost configured properly, does it points to the correct folder? What path do you have in the address bar? Did you check the console as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the file paths are correct (This means that the stylesheet and JavaScript file are in the same location as the HTML file
2. Ensure that your cache is cleared, than refresh the page.